# Kill the process if start time is less than 2 hours

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to kill the process if start time is less than 2 hours.

I have written the below cmdlet to find out the `starttime` but how to find out if is it less than 2 hours:

```
get-process process1 | select starttime
```

There is also a possibility that on some hosts `process1` is not running. so I need to check first `if the process1 is running`

Comment: You can use `Where-Object` to filter for that given the date, by using the `.AddHours()` method and seeing what time is greater than that of 2 hours ago: `Get-Process -Name notepad | Where-Object -Property StartTime -GT (Get-Date).AddHours(-2) | Stop-Process -PassThru`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop of your choice, in this example [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) in addition to an [`if` condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-7.2) to check if the `StartTime` value is lower than 2 hours.

If you need to check first is the process is running then you would need to get all processes and filter by the process name you're looking for. Then check if the returned value from `Where-Object` is `$null` or not.

```
$procName = 'myprocess'
$process = Get-Process | Where-Object Name -EQ $procName
if(-not $process) {
    Write-Warning "$procName not found!"
}
else {
    $process | ForEach-Object {
        if($_.StartTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddHours(-2)) {
            try {
                'Attempting to stop {0}' -f $_.Name
                Stop-Process $_ -Force
                '{0} successfully stopped.' -f $_.Name
            }
            catch {
                Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Please note that I want to kill the process only if `starttime` is less than `2 hours`.

Comment: @meallhour woops, my bad. so lower than 2 hours it is

Comment: There is also a possibility that on some hosts `process1 is not running.` so i need to `check first if the process1 is running.` I have updated my question too.

Comment: @meallhour should be covered with the last update

Comment: I need some modification to the script and created another question for it. 
can you please help to answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71412590