# How to keep checking the process after every 30 minutes?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to `kill the process` if start time is `less than 2 hours.`
I need to `add sleep for 30 mins` if start time is `more than 2 hours.`
I need to `keep repeating` it until the process is no more running.

I have written the below script so far to perform the above action.

```
$procName = 'myprocess'
$process = Get-Process | Where-Object Name -EQ $procName
if(-not $process) {
    Write-Warning "$procName not found!"
}
else {
    $process | ForEach-Object {
        if($_.StartTime -lt [datetime]::Now.AddHours(-2)) {
                Stop-Process $_ -Force
            }
        else {
               sleep(1800)
           }   
        }
    }
}
```

**How to add the above program in a `do-while` or another loop so as to keep checking until the process is no more running?
Also, how to implement a maximum timer of 4 hours?**

Comment: When you say you need to keep checking, is this because the process failed to be stopped due to an error?

Comment: I mean that if the process was started more than 2 hours ago then I don't kill the process and wait for it to stopped by itself. I need to check this after every 30 minutes until I find that the process is no more running.

Comment: Your wording is a little confusing. Less than 2 hours would be 1 hour up to 2. More than 2 would be 3, 4, etc. but, in your script it's killing the processes greater than 2 hours, not less. To make sure I understood then, you want to continuously check the process that are *greater* than 2 hours to see if they stopped, then do what after?

Comment: Yeah I want to continuously check the process that are greater than 2 hours to see if they stopped. I want to check it after every 30 minutes.
By the way,  script so far is not killing the processes greater than 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your `else` condition could look like this using a `do-while` loop:

```
else {
    do {
        "$procName is still running, sleeping for 1800 sec"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1800
    } while(Get-Process | Where-Object Name -EQ $procName)
}
```

However note that this could cause an infinite loop if the process never stops or you implement a maximum timer, etc.

---

Following your comment regarding implementing a maximum timer, there are many ways you could do it, my personal preference would be to use a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0):

```
else {
    $timer = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
    do {
        # Do this while the process is still running AND
        # the timer hasn't yet reached 4 hours
        "$procName is still running, sleeping for 1800 sec"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1800
        $stillRunning = Get-Process | Where-Object Name -EQ $procName
    } while($stillRunning -and $timer.Elapsed.Hours -lt 4)
    $timer.Stop()
}
```

Comment: thanks! how can I modify to implement a maximum timer of 4 hours? I have also updated my question. I think `implementing a max timer will certainly help here.`

Comment: @meallhour see my last edit, hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a windows schedule task that launch your powershell script every 30 minutes or so instead of blocking resource with your powershell that is waiting.

You can launch powershell and pass a script.
PowerShell.exe -File "C:\script.ps1"

Comment: the script has other functionality as well so i cannot use a windows schedule task. there is no issue with blocking resource `so kindly let me know how to add a do-while or another looping here?`